# How do I dynamically load data from my django views to my django template with jquery without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to load data from my django views into my django templates without refreshing the page with jquery. I have a cart function in my views that's returning all the items in a users cart. I would like to display all the items on the click of a button in a django template with jQuery. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my views:

```
def cart(request):
template = loader.get_template("main/cart.html")
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    email = request.user.email
    usercartitems = request.user.cart_item_set.all()
    cartitems = []
    store = ""
    totalprice = 0
    numberofitemsincart = len(cartitems)
    for item in usercartitems:
        quantity = item.product_quantity
        store_id = item.store_id
        product_id = item.product_id
        storedetail = Store_detail.objects.get(pk = store_id)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk = product_id)
        item = {"quantity":quantity, "product":product}
        cartitems.extend([item])
        store = storedetail
        numberofitemsincart = len(cartitems)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk = product_id)
        totalproductprice = product.price * int(quantity)
        totalprice += totalproductprice
    context={
    'store':store,
    'email':email,
    'cartitems':cartitems,
    'numberofitemsincart':numberofitemsincart,
    'totalprice':totalprice,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
elif request.user.is_authenticated is False:
    if request.session.get('cart'):
        allitems = request.session['cart']
        cartitems = []
        totalprice = 0
        for item in allitems.values():
            store_id = item['store_id']
            quantity = item['quantity']
            product_id = item['product_id']
            product = Product.objects.get(pk = product_id)
            store = Store_detail.objects.get(pk = store_id)
            totalproductprice = product.price * int(quantity)
            totalprice += totalproductprice
            cartdict = {'store':store,'product':product,'quantity':quantity,}
            cartitems.append(cartdict)
        context = {
            'cartitems':cartitems,
            'totalprice':totalprice,
        }
    else:
        context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
else:
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#cart').click(
        function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url:"{% url 'main:cart' %}",
            data: {
                  'cartitems': cartitems
                }
            success:function(data){
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to deal with `json` data as a result to your request. If you only have one item to update in your html page, to me it's not necessary to render the whole thing, and `jquery` is one way to go.

I also think it is too complicated to deal with context stuff for that. Here is an example to return your user a `json` response you can then work with in your `jquery` piece of code:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def cart(request):
    try:

        [...] # your stuff

        # define here the json data you want to return, in a list
        your_json_data = [{
            'key1': val1, 
            'key2': val2,
            ...
        }]

        return JsonResponse(your_json_data, safe=False)

    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({})
```

You will then be able to work with the data you just fetched!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))`, you should use the `render` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def cart(request):
    ...

    return render(request, 'main/cart.html', context)
```

Comment: The console.log is not working. Ajax is not getting the data from the backend

Comment: @Osaro added an update, see if that fixes your problem.